# Is this proof sufficient for this problem (linear independence of vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

If $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent then prove that the vectors $2v_1 + 3v_2 + v_3, v_1 - v_2 - v_3, 3v_1 + 5v_2 - v_3$ are also linearly independent.

**My solution:**

Since $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are lin. ind. we know that $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3=0$ only if $c_1,c_2,c_3=0$

We suppose that

$c_4(2v_1 + 3v_2 + v_3) + c_5(v_1 - v_2 - v_3) + c_6(3v_1 + 5v_2 - v_3) = 0$

So

$v_1(2c_4 + c_5 + 3c_6) + v_2(3c_4 - c_5 + 5c_6) + v_3(c_4 - c_5 - c_6) = 0$

We set from the first definition that
$c1 = 2c_4 + c_5 + 3c_6, c_2 = 3c_4 - c_5 + 5c_6, c_3 = c_4 - c_5 - c_6$

and so we see that the vectors in question are lin. ind.

Is this a sufficient proof for this problem? I saw a solution in another problem that involved finding a determinant at the end and i cant wrap my head why

Comment: Linear independence of $v_1, v_2, v_3$ implies that $2c_4+c_5+3c_6 = 3c_4-c_5+5c_6 = c_4-c_5-c_6=0$. However, you haven't shown that $c_4=c_5=c_6=0$.

Comment: you just can't designate those coefficients by $c_i$'s. rather solve those coefficients and show that $c_4=c_5=c_6=0$

Comment: You didn't use the definition of linear independence for $w_1=2v_1+3v_2+v_3$ etc. If $r_1w_1+r_2w_2+r_3w_3=0$, then you have to show that $r_1=r_2=r_3=0$.

Comment: Your "*proof*" would work the same if you chose three identical vectors $\,v_1+v_2+v_3\,$ instead, even though those are obviously not linearly independent.

Comment: You haven't shown that there is not some combination of $c_4,c_5,c_6$ such that $c_1,c_2,c_3 = 0$ and $c_4,c_5,c_6\ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

A)

As you say, from equations:

$$c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3=0 \textit{ only if } c_1,c_2,c_3=0$$

and

$$v_1(2c_4 + c_5 + 3c_6) + v_2(3c_4 - c_5 + 5c_6) + v_3(c_4 - c_5 - c_6) = 0$$

we reach:

$$2c_4 + c_5 + 3c_6 = 3c_4 - c_5 + 5c_6 = c_4 - c_5 - c_6 = 0$$

and solving the system we found $c_4 = c_5 = c_6 = 0$, finishing the proof.

B)

Note the system:

$$2c_4 + c_5 + 3c_6 = 3c_4 - c_5 + 5c_6 = c_4 - c_5 - c_6 = 0$$

can be expressed in matrix form as:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 3\\
3 & -1 & 5\\
1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{matrix}\right) 
\left(\begin{matrix}
c_4\\
c_5\\
c_6
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

multiplying by inverse (assuming it exists):

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
c_4\\
c_5\\
c_6
\end{matrix}\right) =\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & 3\\
3 & -1 & 5\\
1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{matrix}\right) ^ {-1}
\left( \begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

you can calculate the inverse, multiply by (0,0,0) and find $c_4=c_5=c_6=0$. However, note that the values in the inverse are not important, always $c_4=c_5=c_6=0$ after multiply by (0,0,0). The only important thing is "EXIST the inverse?". If it exists, $c_4=c_5=c_6=0$, no matter the exact value of the inverse.

Thus, the problem now is answer "has this matrix an inverse?", that is "is this matrix invertible". And a matrix has inverse only if its determinant is non-zero.

In conclusion, just evaluate the determinant of this matrix. If it is non-zero, the matrix has inverse. If the matrix has inverse, $c_4=c_5=c_6=0$, finishing the proof.

Comment: Thank you, especially the B) solution was very helpful in understanding the subject better

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative by

- $w_1=2v_1 + 3v_2 + v_3$
- $w_2=v_1 - v_2 - v_3$
- $w_3=3v_1 + 5v_2 - v_3$

we have

- $w_1-2w_2=5v_2+3v_3$
- $3w_2-w_3=-8v_2-2v_3$

and then

- $2(w_1-2w_2)+3(3w_2-w_3)=2w_1+7w_2-3w_3=-14v_2$
- $8(w_1-2w_2)+5(3w_2-w_3)=8w_1+13w_2-5w_3=14v_3$

and since $w_2=v_1 - v_2 - v_3\implies v_1=v_2+v_3+w_2$ we have

- $6w_1+20w_2-2w_3=14v_1$

therefore $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ span the same space and therefore they are linerly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & -1 & 5 \\ 1 & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and let $P \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \text{span}(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ be the linear map given by $Pe_j = v_j$. The question can be phrased as are $PAe_1, PAe_2, PAe_3$ linearly independent? This happens if and only if $PA$ is invertible. Since $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ are a basis of $\text{span}(v_1, v_2, v_3)$, $P$ is invertible, so $PA$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is invertible. Now you just have to compute whether $A$ has an inverse or not.